# Force.com IDE Install Error with Eclipse 4.2

Tags: force.com, ide, eclipse

I'm installing the Force.com plugin for Eclipse but received the error below. I'm using Eclipse 4.2 and I received the same error with 4.3. I tried using an older version of Eclipse, 3.6, but the installation continuously timed out after reaching 10% completion.

Here are the application and error details:

- Windows 7
- 64-bit
- jdk 1.7
- jre 7
- Eclipse 4.2 Juno
- Force.com v29.0

An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=epp.package.jee, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
Unable to read repository at http://media.developerforce.com/force-ide/eclipse42/plugins/com.salesforce.ide_29.0.0.201310181333.jar.
Read timed out
Unable to read repository at http://media.developerforce.com/force-ide/eclipse42/plugins/com.salesforce.ide.api_29.0.0.201310181333.jar.
Read timed out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Eclipse 4.2 “Juno” and 4.3 "Kepler" are the most recently supported version of Eclipse.](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Force.com_IDE) 

Thanks to [ManSpan](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/3838/manspan)

Comment: well actually 4.2 and 4.3 are also supported with the winter 14 version. I have installed it on Friday http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Force.com_IDE

Comment: 2 items from above link mentioned by @ManosSpanoudakis
1. Added support for version 4.2 “Juno” and 4.3 "Kepler"
2. Dropped support for version 3.x

Comment: Thats why 3.6 is no more supported from Winter 14.

Comment: Wow! Cool! I'll try Kepler.

Comment: As of 2 months ago, they still officially only supported Java 1.6 though! I had a site that I had to revert back to Java 1.6 before I could successfully collect all of the metadata for it. :-(

Comment: Facing similar situation here. Anyone managed to make it through?? My error message reads "Unable to read repository at http://media.developerforce.com/force-ide/eclipse42/content.xml.
Unable to read repository at http://media.developerforce.com/force-ide/eclipse42/content.xml.
Cannot assign requested address: connect"

Comment: Found the solution. This is more of an Eclipse error, whereby eclipse was trying to use IPv6 to connect. See details here: http://www.flintstudio.com/blog/quick-tip-eclipse-repository-problems-windows-8/#.UvccyfmSz_U. Simply adding  "-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true" to eclipse.ini fixed it.

Comment: thanks earthling!  That fixed it.  You should post it as the answer

Answer (score 1):

You can start fresh and follow instructions step by step...
https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Force.com_IDE_Installation

Answer (score 1):

Try downloading Eclipse classic Standard/SDK and update to salesforce plugin with http://media.developerforce.com/force-ide/eclipse42. It worked for me. Once you updated with the force.com plugin, you can later update the eclipse sdk to the latest version if needed.

http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/index-helios.php
http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-classic-42/junor

Answer (score 0):

Try to install force.com ide from below link

http://media.developerforce.com/force-ide/eclipse42