# Force.com IDE Error "an arror occured while collecting items to be installed"

Tags: error, ide, force.com-ide

While installing force.com IDE am getting this Error:

> an arror occured while collecting items to be installed

please reply anybody with Right solution.

Comment: What version and operating system ?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is more of an Eclipse error it is not able to read some files from the repositories.

Hope [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/20828/force-com-ide-install-error-with-eclipse-4-2) will help you.

Answer (score 0):

This could be a problem with stale cached repository data. Please try again after deleting the p2/org.eclipse.equinox.p2.repository/cache directory from your STS installation. If that doesn't help, you could also try to change the repository URL from "dist.springsource.com..." to "download.springsource.com..."

Hope this will help you